# Alternative gettext lib in C?

Tags: c, localization, android-ndk, gettext

I have an Android NDK project entirely in C. I have a bunch of .po files, and libintl configured currently.

Unfortunately, [according to a Google dev](http://groups.google.com/group/android-ndk/browse_thread/thread/ffd012a047ec2392/1a5248f319206389#1a5248f319206389), it looks like I am SOL expecting to use gettext in my project, as Android doesn't support setting locales at such a low-level.

Are there any ways I can continue to support localization my project?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not shure you are looking for this lib but you can try https://code.google.com/p/mofilereader/downloads/detail?name=moFileReaderSDK-0.1.3.zip